# Symfony2 Doctrine - Database - Preventing simultaneous accesses at the same time?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, symfony, doctrine-orm

I think my current problem is describable very quick.

I have a symfony2 project with doctrine accessing the mysql database.
Now multiple (many) users can visit this page at the same time.

Now, my problem is the following:
Users can click a button to mark himself as a participant of an entry.
An entry can have a maximum of allowed participants.

E.g.:
ENTRY A, max. users = 3 <----- USER A, B, C and D viewing ENTRY A.

Now, A marks himself as an participant by clicking an Ajax Button.
B do the same (not at the same time -> no problem).

Now C and D fight for the last free slot in ENTRY A.
Both click on the button at the same time.

It can happen now that C and D both can join this entry, even if the max. users of 3 is exeeded.

If an user clicks on the Ajax Button, an ajax call gets send.
On the server side, in the ajax handler, my symfony2 code will use doctrine to access the db.
It simply requests the entry from database and checks if the maximum of users already reached.
If not, the user gets saved/marked as an participant of the entry.

But that's not allowed. I want to avoid that 2 users can click on the button at the same time to join the entry.
In this state, max. users in the entry is defined to 3 and the amount of participants for this entry is 4. That's not the goal of this function.

Can you explain me how to fix this?
Do i need table locking or something else?

If it is not exactly clear what the problem is, then just ask.
I look forward to answers and i am grateful for each hint.

Best
titan

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you're using MySQL you could use

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_get-lock
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_release-lock

How you code it is up to you, but it can be used to mitigate concurrency issues like the one you have.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Transaction and concurency on doctrine doc http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/transactions-and-concurrency.html